# PlantUml - Set max width without constraining height

Tags: uml, plantuml

I have a plantUml diagram that looks like this:

[image]

The image has a width of 1234px and a height of 970px.  I need to print the image as part of a report and would like to fit it on a letter sized sheet of paper in portrait orientation.

If I could set the max width of 900px it would fit better in my report.  I don't mind if the diagram becomes significantly longer/taller.

I have tried using various combinations of

```
scale 200 width
scale 700 height
```

But as per the doc, this doesn't do what I want:

> You can use the scale command to zoom the generated image.
>
> You can use either a number or a fraction to define the scale factor.
>   You can also specify either width or height (in pixel). And you can
>   also give both width and height : the image is scaled to fit inside
>   the specified dimension.

**How can I set a max width for my diagram, without changing the font sizes used or constraining the height allowed for my diagram.**

Comment: @sistyfootersdude Any updates on that ?

Comment: @FabioMarreco - No.  None.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go a different route with this. Create the diagram however you please and use the `dpi` skinparam to scale the image up or down when printing, for instance `skinparam dpi 300`

The default is 96 dpi but I've had to go up to as much as 600 to get a decent result.